# Automating Creation of for thousands of Choropleth map creation from table in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a table with a hundred of fields or indicators that am required to visualize by graduation styling to have Choropleth maps. Is there a way how to automate this process in QGIS for quick results.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Can you describe the manual steps in creating one map?